# Overwrite remote .git folder?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo that, when cloned, is quite large (about 30MB) with the actual `src` files only taking up about 1.5MB. The culprit ended up being the contents of the `.git/objects/` folder. I did some cleaning and was able to get the repo size  down to 2.5MB.

I want to push these changes to my remote GitHub repo. I've tried to force push the master branch (in this case it's fine since it's private), but I end up seeing 'Everything up-to-date', which makes sense because none of the `src` files changed.

Is there a way to overwrite the remote `.git` folder? Or sync it with my local repo?

#### Edit

By 'some cleaning', I did not delete anything inside of `.git`. I simply ran a few commands:

```
git fsck --full --unreachable
git repack -a -d
git prune
```

I also updated the `packed-refs` lines I no longer needed.

Comment: If you provide a link to the repository in question, we could have a look at what's going on.

Comment: Note that the size of your local `.git` folder does not reflect the size of the `.git` folder on GitHub's servers.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't delete files in the `.git` folder. There are commands like `git gc` to cleanup your repo. If you want to remove files from your repo you can use `git rm --cached filename` to remove that files or folder from your repo but keep the files locally.

Then you can add that folders to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

> *I have a repo that, when cloned, is quite large (about 30MB)*

That's quite small by today's standards.

If you consider 30 megs of disk "quite large" I have to wonder about your development environment, and how you're using repository clones. If you're short on disk space, it might be [a better use of your time/money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost) to get a bigger disk than spending a bunch of time trying to save 30 megs.

> *By 'some cleaning', I did not delete anything inside of .git. I simply ran a few commands*

Good, deleting files inside .git would be ***bad***.

> *Is there a way to overwrite the remote .git folder? Or sync it with my local repo?*

If you were running your own Git server, yes, but not on Github. Github should be taking care of this sort of repacking for you. If not, your local Git should be doing a `git gc` from time to time. If not, you can do it yourself.

---

What you describe sounds a bit fishy. Large repositories are usually the result of either committing a lot of compressed files, or committing a lot of very large binary files. Git has trouble seeing the differences between those files, or compressing them.

To the former, decompress files before committing them. To Git something like a .gz or .tar.gz or .zip is a blob of binary data. Since it's already compressed, it can't compress it further. Since it can't see the real content, it can't take advantage of storing diffs. So instead of, for example, storing code.tgz, extract it and store the directory.

As for large binary files like images, office documents, video, audio, and the like... Git also has trouble compressing (they're usually already compressed) and diffing them. The solution there is to use [git-lfs (Large File Storage)](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store their actual content them in the cloud. This can greatly reduce the size of a repository.

That reduces the size of the repository going forward, what about the existing history? For that there is the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which lets you rewrite history to [convert large files to use LFS](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5).

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to have small clone size on disk, do shallow clone: `git clone --depth 1` i.e. clone with no history. This is particularly useful when cloning a huge repo with gigabytes of size and 1000s of commits.
- If you want to permanently shrink the repo size on server and have small clone size with history for each future clone, you'd have to do `git filter-branch` and remove some parts of the history (for example useful when you checked in a large file by accident and then deleted etc. - normally git would keep the file forever in history and by default all clones will still have it)
- If you want to get rid of unreachable objects on other machines, you need to do `git gc` or similar command on each host. You can not invoke it remotely in any way. Note that when you overwrite history and `push --force`, the clients who had fetched some removed commits before will retain them - whatever became public once should be treated as public forever. You can do nothing to remotely force remove other people's clones' history. Git (on the client) will garbage collect them automatically after some time but from server perspective you have no control over that.

Comment: Rather than doing this with `git filter-branch`, look into the BFG Repo Cleaner. In the future there is gif-lfs (Large File Support) which can transparently store versions of large files in cloud storage rather than the repository. And you can [use the BFG and git-lfs together](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5) to move large files in old commits into cloud storage.